# I need your advice.

Tags: support, allowed-questions, specific-question, editing

I need some good advice. There is one math.problem which I asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/183786/equation-with-divisors-ii). It is my second attempt. I have some new ideas and new results, but question is already big enough. I don't want to delete anything in the old text but I realize that more information makes a mess. I don't know whether it is possible in this situation to create a new question? Or it is not welcome here?

Comment: Why don't you post that as an answer in the same thread, perhaps with a warning that these are partial, however, new results. I don't know if people would want it CW but I certainly have no problem with it; no need for CW IMO.

Comment: This sounds reasonble.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your updates are indeed *updates* then go ahead and improve your question.

But if your new information is only related to that question and could be asked as a follow-up question, then I suggest this last solution. This will come in handy for you too, because you'll get a better and more focused answer. Not to mention that it'll be harder to answer if you include many questions inside a single question.

Asking follow-up questions is totally legitimate and, why not consider it, it'll increase your reputation. :)

Comment: If you do ask a follow-up question, please be sure to include links both ways between it and the original.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Good idea. :)